# As per W3C can we add onclick inside li tag?

Tags: seo, html, w3c-validation

I have 2 questions:

1. As W3C can we add onclick inside `<li>` tag?
2. Will this affect anything to do with SEO?

For example:

```
<li onclick="newDoc()">Click!</li>

function newDoc() {location.assign("http://validator.w3.org/");}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, inline JavaScript is a no no. You seperate your HTML, PHP, CSS and JS files into different files. Inline styling/coding only makes bad maintainable code. You'll forget where you did what, and debugging will become a pain in the ass.

For SEO, if your pages are HTML(x/5) valid, no problems. As long as you don't expect them to run JavaScript (e.g.: show content only after click).

*Yes, there are some situations where inline style/coding is OK, but they're exceptions.*